# Apps scripts - как скриптом переместить содержимое ячейки вместо со ссылкой?

Tags: javascript

Искал по инету как с помощью Apps script перенести содержимое ячейки вместе со ссылкой. Не нашел. Может здесь кто подскажет
`var values = ss2.getRange(1,3,1,4).getValues();`
собираю в переменную данные из диапазона ячеек. Но первое значение в этом диапазоне имеет ссылку типа `=HYPERLINK("http//"; "Go")`
Далее я вставляю этот блок данных в другой лист в указанные ячейки:
`var values = ss1.getRange(lr+1,1,1,4).setValues(values);`
Данные успешно переносятся на другой лист, но значение, которое было со ссылкой, переносится без ссылки.
Как-то можно сделать, чтоб и ссылка переносилась в новое место?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос использованием 'getFormula()' и 'setFormula()' отдельно для ячейки с ссылкой. Может не совсем грамотно, но работает